# Server block for nginx is not working as expected

Tags: apache, nginx, nginx-location

I have a basic server block in my /etc/nginx/default file like so

```
server{

    listen 80;
    server_name infinity infinity.com www.infinity.com;

    location / {

        root /home/zrehan/projects/infinityrollcordova/www/homeScreen;
        index.html index.htm;
    }

}
```

Then I enabled the sites like so

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

the result is this

```
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 28 14:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K Jan 28 12:49 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jan 28 14:28 default -> ../sites-available/default
```

Then I added the infinity in my hosts file like so

```
127.0.0.1     localhost    zrehan.com    infinity.com
```

The problem I am facing is

1.For zrehan.com and infinity.com it is opening the infinity.com's homepage

2.and I get this error in infinity.com

[image]

Comment: does this errors occur also on `zrehan.com` or only in `infinity.com`? have you checked you nginx logs (access/error logs)? is there something interesting?

Comment: Yes it occurs in zrehan.com as well.

Comment: error log reads `2018/01/28 15:54:58 [error] 7658#7658: *22 open() "/home/zrehan/projects/infinityrollcordova/www/homeScreen/assets/svg/collectablesNocolor.svg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: infinity.com, request: "GET /assets/svg/collectablesNocolor.svg HTTP/1.1", host: "infinity.com", referrer: "http://infinity.com/"
`
is this something to do with absolute path?

Comment: Actually this: `/assets/svg/collectablesNocolor.svg` is relative path to your `root` in nginx configuration. Nginx is clearly stating where it is looking for files, if they are not there, definitely 404 (not found) error is natural result in that case. Fix your paths to resources and it should work.

Comment: my index.html file is in homeScreen folder so I have given that as my root folder. This shouldn't be done?

Comment: Fine, your `index.html` is loaded, but your `index.html` is loading other resources, like that `.svg` file. Which does not exists there. Either put correctly all resources under `root` directory or try to reconfigure you nginx to look for this resources in other dirs. For more details have a look in [this guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) or [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/)